# Updating a value of Flag in database

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, ibatis

I am setting a value of a flag from Holder where we describe getter and setter method usually. I want to update the flag in the database when I save the Product Configuration. Say, before saving a Product configuration the flag was "N", now I want to use the product Configuration and update the value of a flag accordingly. I am not able to reflect a value in database. Do I need to write insert statement, if so where?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You must perform an UPDATE statement (because before the product configuration your flag was N so you must update it to Y)

Comment: Thanks @JoeTaras that answers my question. I have been looking for mapping and query so that I can add my flag to the existing insert statement so as to update the Table values. but, unfortunately, can't find the actual query where I have to insert my flag.

Answer (score 0):

Update you flag in DB and commit it as Update is a DML statement.

Answer (score 0):

use update statement:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1='Y' [WHERE Clause]
```

depending on your database, where clause can be selection of

the single row

```
id = 123
```

group having similiar properties

```
some_property = 5
```

or all - then skip it...